# After Removing Hot Towel SPA Package BundleConfig Does Not Exist in Current Context

Tags: single-page-application

I am writing my first Single page application and started out with the Hot Towel Template.  However, requirements have changed and I no longer want to use Hot Towel.  So, I removed it using package manager taking care to leave all the other files for existing dependencies.

Unfortunatley, my build thorws the error:

```
Error   1   The name 'BundleConfig' does not exist in the current context
```

Global.asax.cs is comprised of:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MMG.Legacy.StudySiteComm.Web
{
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
// visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
 }
}
```

How do I resolve this build error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not creating any bundles, then you can just remove the offending line entirely.

The BundleConfig class is not a special class - it's just a standard static class that provides a convenient, single place to add bundles to the System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection.

If you create a brand-new MVC project using the Visual Studio "basic" MVC project template, you'll see it creates its own BundleConfig file under the App_Start folder.